# Format String to Float with two decimal places

Tags: scala

I have this code ( which is not working unfortunately):

```
object Number
{
    case class Number(number: Float)

    def fromString(value: String): Either[Throwable, Number] =
    {
        Try("%.2f".format(value).replace(',', '.').toFloat)
            .map(Number)
            .toEither
    }
}


def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = Number.fromString("100,555")
```

my goal is to have a Float, that looks like this:

```
100.56
```

But for now the output is:

> Left(java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f !=
> java.lang.String)

**So my questin is:
How can I get my wanted output?**

**Or is there a function to format and round a number like number_format in PHP**

Comment: I am not sure, but doesn't Scala support the following ?? "100".toFloat

Comment: No, it does not, at least it is not working for me :(

Comment: It looks like you're confused about **formatting** and **parsing**. The title of your question suggests you want to **format** a number into a string, but your code looks like you want to **parse** a number. Anyway, `"%.2f".format(value)` needs `value` to be a `Float`, but you're passing it a `String`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that as well, but when I do something like that: **Try("%.2f".format(value.toFloat).replace(',', '.'))
   .map(Number)
   .toEither**. Then I´m getting the following error message: **Found:    Float => Entity.Number.Number
Required: String => Entity.Number.Number
   .map(Number)**

Comment: If you are rounding you will get `100.56` not `100.55`.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion can be done like this:

```
def fromString(value: String): Either[Throwable, Number] =
    Try(Number(value.replace(',', '.').toFloat))
        .toEither
```

Rounding a binary to a decimal internally is a bad idea, but this is how it would work:

```
def fromString(value: String): Either[Throwable, Number] = {
  Try(
    Number(math.round(value.replace(',', '.').toFloat * 100.0) / 100.0f)
  ).toEither
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but why shouldn´t I round a binary internally? :)

Comment: Decimal fractions are not necessarily stored accurately in binary, so rounding to the nearest decimal fraction introduces rounding errors beyond the decimal rounding error. Unless the calculation really does involve decimal rounding, better to do all calculations to maximum accuracy without rounding, and only round when displaying or testing the results.